# Desctruct a variable from a return object of a function insde another return object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I know that I can do `const { name: userName }= getName()`, and then `return { userName }`.

```
function returnName(){
  return { name: "Jason" }
}


function getUserName(){
  return {
    userName : getName()
  }
}
```

Can I destruct it inside that only one return block in the `getUserName`?

```
function getUserName(){
 return {
   userName : {[getName()] : name} // I know it doesnt work, but want something like this
 }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you are looking for a trivial property access:

```
function getUserName() {
  return {
    userName: getName().name
  };
}
```

Don't make it more complicated than it needs to be, you don't need any destructuring here!

Comment: yeah ,I know how to do that,but destructing is so cool, and I have having trouble destructing like right there, or know if it's even possible. Also If there is another inject inside the name, like fist name and last name, then I will have to do another . first name.

Comment: @JOHNC Well no, it's not possible here - a destructuring assignment is not an expression that produces a new value. And you shouldn't use programming language features just because they are "so cool" anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Like bergi pointed out you just can use:

```
function getUserName() {
  return {
    userName: getName().name
  };
}
```

I would like to add the steps for further clarification (so you know exactly what happens):

1. `getName()` function returns an object, this object (although it is inside another object literal) is just a regular javascript object.
2. To retrieve a value of a key from this object you can simply use the dot `.` operator